# Wave equations for transmission lines and initial value

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-circuits, electric-fields, voltage

let's consider for instance a general transmission line:

[image]

By applying the circuit theory equations (Kirchhoff and Ohm) to the elementary circuit $\Delta Z$ we get the telegrapher's equations:

$$\frac{\partial V(z)}{\partial z}=-(R+j\omega L)I(z) \tag {1}$$
$$\frac{\partial I(z)}{\partial z}=-(G+j\omega C)V(z) \tag {2}$$

$$\downarrow$$

$$V(z)=V_0^+e^{-\gamma z}+V_0^-e^{\gamma z} \tag{3}$$
$$I(z)=I_0^+e^{-\gamma z}+I_0^-e^{\gamma z} \tag{4}$$

So, the solutions of these equations are voltage and current exponential functions. Both equations may be also used to derive the following wave equations, which lead to the same exponential functions for V and I:

$$\frac{d^2V}{dz^2}-\gamma^2V=0 \tag{5}$$

$$\frac{d^2I}{dz^2}-\gamma^2I=0 \tag{6}$$

Now, I have the following doubt. Consider the following transmission line, in which I put the origin of z - axis in a different point.

[image]

The transmission line starts at the position $z_0$. Which is now the solution for $V(z)$ and $I(z)$? Surely the telegrapher's equations do not change, since the procedure to determine them is does not depend on the poisition in which the elementary circuit is considered. So I think that the position $z_0$ is something like a boundary condition for the differential equations, but I do not have a precise view of this problem.

Comment: As you surmised, the general solution is the same, but the constants depend on the boundary conditions.